# If x is a value in this dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to do this:

```
d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
if 4 in d:
    print('Aha!')
```

but I want to read from the values and not the keys. What's the Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest to *rethink* your problem and solution. If you need lookup by some `v`, then a `k->v` mapping is not a suitable data structure.

Comment: I'm using a dict because I'm parsing strings and replacing those which match any of the regexes in the dict to their predetermined values, so for that a dict works perfectly. My question came about because I need to omit a later operation for those values which were affected by the dict. So it's a bit of an awkward flop. I considered putting them into a temporary list after I replace them, but I'd rather not have more variables than I need. :)

Comment: @ArturSapek, are you sure a dict matches your needs perfectly? if it's a matching_regexp:replacement_string dict, then you need to iterate through it (iteritems), so you might as well reverse the mapping (replacement_string:matching_regexp). Also, unless you are using a py 2.7+ collections.OrderedDict, then the values come out in any order... which is unlikely to be a good idea for such replacements. Alternatively why not store the values you want to skip in a temporary set (not a list) - you can then call it `replacement_strings` if it helps the readability of the code.

Comment: Greetings from the distant future! A performant solution would be to maintain *two* dicts, storing the mappings in both directions. So you'd have your `d` as it is, and also have `index` with the reverse mappings. As you're building `d`, each time you store a `k=>v` entry with `d[k] = v`, you'd also do `index[v] = k`. And when you want to know if a value is among the values of `d`, you'd check whether that value is in the keys of `index`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`values`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)<sup>1</sup>:

```
d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
if 4 in d.values():
    print('Aha!')
```

Note that this will be much slower than a key lookup because it will potentially require inspecting all values in the dictionary. If you need to perform this operation often you might want to consider storing the values in a `set`.

---

<sup>1</sup>[`itervalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) in Python 2

Comment: The dictionary I'm working with has fewer than a dozen pairs, I could have done a messy for-loop hack but I wanted to be clean. Thank you, this works perfectly for me but I'll keep your advice in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3):

The nature of a dictionary is that you cannot efficiently test whether or not a value is present in the way that you can test whether a key is present.

You need to iterate over the dictionary testing each value, although this can be done transparently using the code that Mark suggests. If you have large dictionaries then performance may be an issue and you may require a different data structure.