# Python: using raw_input checking if answer is in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, raw-input

I have 50 states and capitals. The game is where the user is given the 50 states in a random order and must input the correct capital for each state.

I want to create a dictionary with all the states and capitals, but I don't know how to make the program check if the user put in the correct capital.

```
# Game Start
import random
states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'] 
random.shuffle(states)
for state in states:
    answer = raw_input ("%s" % state)

# DICTIONARY
Dict = {'Alabama':Montgomery, 'Alaska':Juneau, 'Arizona':Phoenix, 'Arkansas':Little_Rock, 'California':Sacramento, 'Colorado':Denver, 'Connecticut':Hartford, 'Delaware':Dover, 'Florida':Tallahassee, 'Georgia':Atlanta, 'Hawaii':Honolulu, 'Idaho':Boise, 'Illinois':Springfield, 'Indiana':Indianapolis, 'Iowa':Des_Moines, 'Kansas':Topeka, 'Kentucky':Frankfort, 'Louisiana':Baton_Rouge, 'Maine':Augusta, 'Maryland':Annapolis, 'Massachusetts':Boston, 'Michigan':Lansing, 'Minnesota':Saint_Paul, 'Mississippi':Jackson, 'Missouri':Jefferson_City, 'Montana':Helena, 'Nebraska':Lincoln, 'Nevada':Carson_City, 'New Hampshire':Concord, 'New Jersey':Trenton, 'New Mexico':Sante_Fe, 'New York':Albany, 'North Carolina':Raleigh, 'North Dakota':Bismarck, 'Ohio':Columbus, 'Oklahoma':Oklahoma_City, 'Oregon':Salem, 'Pennsylvania':Harrisburg, 'Rhode Island':Providence, 'South Carolina':Columbia, 'South Dakota':Pierre, 'Tennessee':Nashville, 'Texas':Austin, 'Utah':Salt_Lake_City, 'Vermont':Montpelier, 'Virginia':Richmond, 'Washington':Olympia, 'West Virginia':Charleston, 'Wisconsin':Madison, 'Wyoming':Cheyenne}
```

How do I check if the answer is in the dictionary? Also, python tells me that name 'Dict" is not defined

Comment: `answer==Dict[state]` Also, define `Dict` in the beginning; probably near the `states` definition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8090402/5985593 
Also if the error keeps coming that 'Dict' not defined, maybe try a name like new_dict = { ... } or so. It's possible that Dict is a keyword in python. Not sure about that one though.

Comment: @JC97 `dict` is a keyword, not `Dict`. :)

Comment: Ya it's still telling me that name new_dict is not defined /: .

Comment: @ClutchRL Define it in the beginning.

Comment: @frederick99 oh okay, sorry than. Wasn't sure about that one ;)

Comment: @frederick99 Defined it in the beginning, now it's tellng me "Montgomery" is not defined.  Did I create my dictionary wrong?

Comment: @ClutchRL Just add quotes around all the capital names, like the state names. The quotes let python know that it is a literal and not a variable.

Comment: @ClutchRL You should make the dictionary values to be from string type, like the keys of the dictionary (wrap them with '). They are strings, not variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import random

capitals = {'Alabama':'Montgomery', 'Alaska':'Juneau', 'Arizona':'Phoenix', 'Arkansas':'Little_Rock', 'California':'Sacramento', 'Colorado':'Denver', 'Connecticut':'Hartford', 'Delaware':'Dover', 'Florida':'Tallahassee', 'Georgia':'Atlanta', 'Hawaii':'Honolulu', 'Idaho':'Boise', 'Illinois':'Springfield', 'Indiana':'Indianapolis', 'Iowa':'Des_Moines', 'Kansas':'Topeka', 'Kentucky':'Frankfort', 'Louisiana':'Baton_Rouge', 'Maine':'Augusta', 'Maryland':'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts':'Boston', 'Michigan':'Lansing', 'Minnesota':'Saint_Paul', 'Mississippi':'Jackson', 'Missouri':'Jefferson_City', 'Montana':'Helena', 'Nebraska':'Lincoln', 'Nevada':'Carson_City', 'New Hampshire':'Concord', 'New Jersey':'Trenton', 'New Mexico':'Sante_Fe', 'New York':'Albany', 'North Carolina':'Raleigh', 'North Dakota':'Bismarck', 'Ohio':'Columbus', 'Oklahoma':'Oklahoma_City', 'Oregon':'Salem', 'Pennsylvania':'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island':'Providence', 'South Carolina':'Columbia', 'South Dakota':'Pierre', 'Tennessee':'Nashville', 'Texas':'Austin', 'Utah':'Salt_Lake_City', 'Vermont':'Montpelier', 'Virginia':'Richmond', 'Washington':'Olympia', 'West Virginia':'Charleston', 'Wisconsin':'Madison', 'Wyoming':'Cheyenne'}
states = list(capitals.keys())

random.shuffle(states)
for state in states:
    answer = raw_input("%s" % state)
    if answer == capitals[state]:
        print 'Correct!'
    else:
        print 'Wrong!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Game Start
import random
states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']


###DICTIONARY: Should be defined before you use it
Dict = {'Alabama':Montgomery, 'Alaska':Juneau, 'Arizona':Phoenix, 'Arkansas':Little_Rock, 'California':Sacramento, 'Colorado':Denver, 'Connecticut':Hartford, 'Delaware':Dover, 'Florida':Tallahassee, 'Georgia':Atlanta, 'Hawaii':Honolulu, 'Idaho':Boise, 'Illinois':Springfield, 'Indiana':Indianapolis, 'Iowa':Des_Moines, 'Kansas':Topeka, 'Kentucky':Frankfort, 'Louisiana':Baton_Rouge, 'Maine':Augusta, 'Maryland':Annapolis, 'Massachusetts':Boston, 'Michigan':Lansing, 'Minnesota':Saint_Paul, 'Mississippi':Jackson, 'Missouri':Jefferson_City, 'Montana':Helena, 'Nebraska':Lincoln, 'Nevada':Carson_City, 'New Hampshire':Concord, 'New Jersey':Trenton, 'New Mexico':Sante_Fe, 'New York':Albany, 'North Carolina':Raleigh, 'North Dakota':Bismarck, 'Ohio':Columbus, 'Oklahoma':Oklahoma_City, 'Oregon':Salem, 'Pennsylvania':Harrisburg, 'Rhode Island':Providence, 'South Carolina':Columbia, 'South Dakota':Pierre, 'Tennessee':Nashville, 'Texas':Austin, 'Utah':Salt_Lake_City, 'Vermont':Montpelier, 'Virginia':Richmond, 'Washington':Olympia, 'West Virginia':Charleston, 'Wisconsin':Madison, 'Wyoming':Cheyenne}

random.shuffle(states)
for state in states:
    answer = raw_input ("%s" % state)
    if Dict[state] == answer:
        pass # Do something in case of right answer
    else:
        pass # what do you want in case of wrong answer
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this one tested and it works just fine. But it's in Python 3, so you'll need to do some minor adjustments.

```
import random

states =['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona']
random.shuffle(states)

# dictionary need to be stated beforehand to check the input
# use '' for the state capital
state_dict = {'Alabama':'Montgomery', 'Alaska':'Juneau', 'Arizona':'Phoenix'}

for state in states:
  answer = input("%s " %state)
  if answer==(state_dict[state]):
      print ("Correct")
  else :
      print ("False")
```

Comment: Why use a separate list? Why not just use state_dict.keys()?

Comment: @MaxNoe cause from what I read, he/she wanted it to be shuffled, and you can't shuffle a dictionary without making a new list.

Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895028/randomly-shuffling-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: See my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double book keeping, you can use `random.sample` on the dictionary items.

It's also a lot more pythonic, because you do loop directly over key and value and are not doing a loop over a key and then a lookup:

```
import random

state_capitols = {
    'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
    'Alaska': 'Juneau',
    'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
}

for state, capitol in random.sample(state_capitols.items(), len(state_capitols)):
    answer = input('What is the capitol of {}? '.format(state))

    if answer == capitol:
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('Wrong!')
```