# Find intersection of two arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am practicing leetcode. Here is the question. https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-arrays-ii/:

> Given two integer arrays `nums1` and `nums2`, return an array of their intersection. Each element in the result must appear as many times as it shows in both arrays and you may return the result in any order.

Where I am doing the mistake?

```
def intersect(nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    ht = dict()
    length1 = len(nums1)
    length2 = len(nums2)
    longer = []
    smaller = []
    intersection = []
    if length1 > length2:
        longer = nums1
        smaller = nums2
    else:
        longer = nums2
        smaller = nums1
    
    for i in range(len(longer)):
        ht[i] = longer[i]
        
    for j in range(len(smaller)):
        if smaller[j] in ht:
            intersection.append(smaller[j])
        else:
            j += 1
    return intersection
```

The answer is accepted for

```
Input: nums1 = [1,2,2,1], nums2 = [2,2]
Output: [2,2]
```

However, it fails for

```
Input: nums1 = [4,9,5], nums2 = [9,4,9,8,4]
Output: [4,9]
```

My output is `[4]`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have kept the longer array's (nums2) all elements in ht.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as duplicate of [If x is a value in this dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090391/if-x-is-a-value-in-this-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: There are several stuffs that seems wrong to me, that I detail later.

My biggest advice is that, in this function, you have two steps "count number in list" and "calc intersection of lists". You should code them separately, make some test cases to check that it works, then run the whole loop.
(With these test cases, you'll quickly find what went wrong)

---

What seems wrong to me:

1)

```
for i in range(len(longer)):
    ht[i] = longer[i]
```

Here, I imagine you'd like to count the number of instances. For example, if nums1 = [5, 8, 8], you'd like a dict
{5: 1, 8: 2}

It's not what your loop is doing. It's saying what number was at which index
(your loop returns {1: 5, 2: 8, 3: 8})

And it's not very pythonic to do "for i in range(len(list))". You should do:

```
for number in in longer:
   ht[number] = ht.get(number, 0) + 1
```

2. 

```
for j in range(len(smaller)):
    if smaller[j] in ht:
        intersection.append(smaller[j])
    else:
        j += 1
```

Why would you increase your index j ?
Also, you need to reduce hf[number[j]] when you encounter it

```
for number in smaller:
    if ht.get(number, 0) > 0:
        intersection.append(number)
        ht[number] -= 1
```

---

What I would code

```
from collections import Counter

 def calc_intersect(nums1, nums2):
     num_to_count_1 = Counter(nums1)
     intersect = []
     for num in nums2:
         if num_to_count_1[num] > 0:
             intersect.append(num)
             num_to_count_1[num] -= 1
     return intersect
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the valid points. This is insightful. Also, would you please mention the effect of using Counter in space and time complexity? Would counter contribute to the time and space complexity?

Comment: I don't know the underlying code, but it should be O(n) and using the same space as the resulting dictionnary.
Also, it has some C implementation or something, because it's faster that doing the dictionnary by yourself. (I remember some blog post that compared ways to count, and Counter was close to, if not, the best)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are checking if `smaller[j] in ht` which will by default check that each `smaller[j]` is in the keys of ht. The keys are ht you set to the indexes of the longer array.

You could just replace with `if smaller[j] in ht.values()`, but you could just do away with `ht` dict and achieve it by checking if `smaller[j]` is in `longer`.

However, the current approach doesn't work, as comparing from longest to smallest will always be flawed as the longest may have [1,1] and the shortest just [1], or in reverse, so you would always achieve a different result.

Here is another solution that counts the values in each list. Then it will iterate through the keys of both and any in common, it will take the min value and multiple this by the key to give you the result. eg. if you had [1,2,2,1] and [2,2], then 2 = 2 in both list counts. Resulting in a min count of 2, multiplied by the key 2 would give you an output of [2,2].

See below;

```
def intersect(nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    ht1 = dict()
    ht2 = dict()
    intersection = []
    
    for num1 in nums1:
        ht1[num1] = ht1[num1] + 1 if num1 in ht1 else 1
        
    for num2 in nums2:
        ht2[num2] = ht2[num2] + 1 if num2 in ht2 else 1

    for key in ht2.keys():
        if key in ht1:
            intersection += key * [min([ht2[key],ht1[key]])]
        
    return intersection
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the values part. Doing that I can't pass for nums1 as [3,1,2]
nums2 as [1,1]. Since both, arrays have only one 1. the expected output is [1]. However, mine is [1,1]. How do I check this?

Comment: you could apply a set(intersection) to remove the duplicate

Comment: I changed ht to set using ht = set() and still couldn't pass for nums1 as [3,1,2] nums2 as [1,1]. Still the output is same.

Comment: IF you change your return to `return list(set(intersection))` does it give you the correct answer of `[1]` ?

Comment: then it will fail for the conditions where there are two elements in both arrays. Eg. Input: [1,2,2,1] [2,2], Expected Output: [2,2]. My output[2]

Comment: yes, good point! I've suggested an alternative solution above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) which is a very fast tool. Then the code would be

```
intersect1 = [el for el in nums1 if el in nums2]
intersect2 = [el for el in nums2 if el in nums1]

if len(intersect1) < len(intersect 2):
    result = intersect1
else:
    result = intersect2
```

You need to compute two intersect lists to get the correct result. The smaller intersect list is the correct one.

Comment: List comprehension is interesting. Thank you for suggesting, will look into this!

Answer (score 0):

You've made it more complicated than it really is. Try this:

```
class Solution():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def intersect(self):
        return [x for x in self.a if x in self.b]
    
print(Solution([4,9,5],[9,4,9,8,4]).intersect())
```